# How do I get varnish to return in the http response header from which backend it took the response?

Tags: varnish

I have three servers in the backend, with a round robin director.

I would like varnish to write a X-Server-By header with the name or ip of the server from which the response was fetched, how can this be done?

Answer (score 12):

In Varnish 3.0.2 I use:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    set beresp.http.X-Backend = beresp.backend.name;
}
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: For Varnish 4, `vcl_fetch` has been renamed `vcl_backend_response`. Otherwise this works there too.

Answer (score 4):

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    set obj.http.X-Backend = req.backend;
}
```

Tested on 2.0.6 in my (non round robin) setup. It should give you something to go on.

Comment: that just displays the backend id, not the individual server

Comment: In Varnish 3+ this should be: `set beresp.http.X-Backend = req.backend;`, however it will still only report the backend's id so it will not be that useful with round-robin backends.

Comment: This is not the way to do it.  Set the header on the backend.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the header on your web server eg x-host: server2 and then varnish will return that as part of the response to a cache hit.

I have this working on apache and it works perfectly.

Comment: Do it this way, trying to set the header in Varnish doesn't make sense. Set it at the backend itself and Varnish will pass it on to the client.

Answer (score -1):

The following is not tested, but might get you started:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    set resp.http.X-Served-By = server.hostname;
    deliver;
}
```

Comment: that gives you the name of het varnish server